# Excel - Stacked Columns Compare Per Month and Year

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to show the following data

| Year | Month | Client Type A | Client Type B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Jan | 44 | 45 |
| 2023 | Feb | 35 | 24 |
| 2023 | Mar | 48 | 45 |
| 2023 | Apr | 28 | 25 |
| 2023 | May | 0 | 0 |
| 2022 | Jan | 30 | 27 |
| 2022 | Feb | 34 | 47 |
| 2022 | Mar | 49 | 44 |
| 2022 | Apr | 28 | 39 |
| 2022 | May | 37 | 0 |
| 2021 | Jan | 18 | 17 |
| 2021 | Feb | 25 | 29 |
| 2021 | Mar | 25 | 24 |
| 2021 | Apr | 31 | 20 |
| 2021 | May | 34 | 58 |

Like this chart

[image: Chart]

I am really not finding a way. Perhaps I am using the wrong type of chart to display what I want. But the stacked column chart feels right.

I got it working in pivot chart, but would like to a non pivot option if possible.
[image: Working Pivot]

Any tips to get me to the end result will be great.

Comment: I kind of got it right with pivot chart. Will add the screen shot to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you are on the right track with the stacked column chart. The issue is the sorting of the data, which is taken care of, to some extent by design, in the Pivot table.

What you want to achieve is that your data is sorted according to the months (small to large) and potentially year (small to large). You could sort manually or include a helper column with the numeric months and then sort via `Data -> Sort`:

```
Sort by: "Month Num" -> Cell Values -> Smallest to Largest
Then by: "Year" -> Cell Values -> Smallest to Largest
```

Once you sorted your data, you create the chart with your initial columns (i.e., Year, Month, Client Type A, and Client Type B) using the `Stacked Column` Option.

Depending of you specific design preferences, you might need to take care of, e.g., (i) spaces between the columns or (ii) the axis labels. (i) Could be achieved by including an empty row in your data. (ii) If you want to have only the years on the axis and spanning the month names across the years respectively, you could change the axis labels to include only the years, and put a text box that spans across the years that include the month name. To change the axis labels select the chart then go to `Chart Design`-> `Select Data` -> `Horizonatl (Category) Axis Labels` -> `Edit` -> `Select only the years`. In addition, you can also specify the angle of the axis labels according to your needs, or other design aspects such as color etc.

The final chart looks as follows:

[image: Chart]

The data used is as follows:

| Year | Month | Client Type A | Client Type B | Month Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Jan | 18 | 17 | 1 |
| 2022 | Jan | 30 | 27 | 1 |
| 2023 | Jan | 44 | 45 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021 | Feb | 25 | 29 | 2 |
| 2022 | Feb | 34 | 47 | 2 |
| 2023 | Feb | 35 | 24 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021 | Mar | 25 | 24 | 3 |
| 2022 | Mar | 49 | 44 | 3 |
| 2023 | Mar | 48 | 45 | 3 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021 | Apr | 31 | 20 | 4 |
| 2022 | Apr | 28 | 39 | 4 |
| 2023 | Apr | 28 | 25 | 4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021 | May | 34 | 58 | 5 |
| 2022 | May | 37 | 0 | 5 |
| 2023 | May | 0 | 0 | 5 |